# FGLRX stopped working after an update

Tags: 14.04, fglrx

After an update last week my ATI proprietary driver i.e. FGLRX stopped working.
Which means I had to go into recovery and remove `fglrx fglrx-pxpress fglrx-amdcccle`.

I reinstalled fglrx successfully but it says it does not detect any graphics card

NOTE: I have ATI Radeon 7670M graphics on my laptop

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427228/how-fix-ati-fglrx-driver-after-kernel-upgrade
It might have relevance to you, especially if the kernel was one of the updated packages.  The concept you are looking for specifically is "dkms" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support which is what you use to assign modules (proprietary ones like fglrx) to your current installed kernel.

Comment: But that solution is for an earlier version of fglrx and ubuntu 12.04 also the changes suggested in that solution have already been made default in fglrx

Comment: What I'm saying is that if your kernel was upgraded then use dkms to link fglrx to your new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem finally.

There was no `amdcccle` or `fglrxinfo` or `aticonfig` even after installing fglrx

The reason for it was that the essential executable files were not there in the correct folders. So I did it by making some soft links as shown below:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/aticonfig /usr/bin/aticonfig
ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/ati/ /etc/ati
```

Even after that aticonfig --initial gave me error

> ERROR: No supported adapters detected

The following command solved the problem

```
/usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibGL amd
```

and then reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall 4.4 kernel (came as update) and with synaptic check to install `fglrx-updates`. Synaptic automatically removed incompatible (xenial) packages (xserver for example) and after reboot fglrx works.